# How does this circuit oscillate?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, oscillator

I once found out that basis of this circuit looks like a Royer oscillator. What makes this circuit oscillate?  Especially, it is still not clear in my mind that what is the function of **capacitors** and the **diodes at the bases of the NPN transistors.** Is there a way to tune the passive elements in the base drive?
*[image: emphasized text]*

Comment: Such things are imho a perfect opportunity to learn a decent simulator and simulate it and look what is happening and why.

Comment: +1 for simulator. You have drawn multiple D1's but the base diodes are protection diodes. RC sets drive level.

Comment: I think important thing here is to realize that inductors Lf are on the same core as 1:N transformer.

Comment: @sstobbe Thanks for the answer. Can you please a bit clarify what do you mean by ''RC sets drive level''